# I need help getting flutter to run on Mac iOS

Tags: ios, android-studio, flutter

I have been work on this problem for a couple of days now. I can not get my flutter app to run on Mac iOS. It runs fine on my Windows machine but I have read that I need to create it on iOS if I want to get it into the Apple Store.

I am using Android Studio to create the app but when I run it on Mac iOS I get the following message:
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 12 Pro Max in debug mode...
Running Xcode build...
Xcode build done. 44.9s
Waiting for iPhone 12 Pro Max to report its views...
Debug service listening on ws://127.0.0.1:57221/5QGegVQYbv0=/ws
Syncing files to device iPhone 12 Pro Max...
[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: [core/not-initialized] Firebase has not been correctly initialized. Have you added the "GoogleService-Info.plist" file to the project?

```
View the iOS Installation documentation for more information: https://firebaseextended.github.io/flutterfire/docs/installation/ios
#0 MethodChannelFirebase.initializeApp (package:firebase_core_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_firebase.dart:86:9)

#1 Firebase.initializeApp (package:firebase_core/src/firebase.dart:43:25)
#2 main (package:tonnah/main.dart:19:18)
#3 _runMainZoned.. (dart:ui/hooks.dart:231:25)
#4 _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1190:13)
#5 _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1093:19)
#6 _runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1630:10)
#7 runZonedGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1618:12)
#8 _runMainZoned. (dart:ui/hooks.dart:223:5)
#9 _startIsolate.<…>
```

...and then it stops. I have added the GoogleService-info.plist file to the project root directory. I have tried it in the iOS directory but I get the same results.

I am willing to get someone on my Mac with me and have them help me setup the project correctly.

Comment: Looks like a Firebase issue more than a flutter issue.  Does the counter app work ok?

Answer (score 1):

You need to go into Xcode and add GoogleService-info.plist in the Runner folder under the Runner App (so 2 times Runner). I think you download this file from the Firebase console, if I am not mistaken

Comment: If this helped you, accepting the answer would be a nice gesture